# How to retrieve PL/SQL record type in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, user-defined-types

A shared package exists which defines a student record type and a function which returns a student:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE shared.student_utils IS
  --aggregates related data from several tables
  TYPE student_rec IS RECORD (
    id       student.id%TYPE,
    username student.username%TYPE,
    name     student.name%TYPE,
    phone    phone.phone%TYPE
    /*etc.*/
  );

  FUNCTION get_student(student_id IN student.id%TYPE) RETURN student_rec;
END;
```

Now, I'm writing a package that provides a API for an Apex application to consume. In particular, I need to provide the student record and other relevant data in a format that can be selected via SQL (and displayed in a report page in Apex.)

So far I've been trying to find the most direct way to select the data in SQL. Obviously, a record type cannot be used in SQL, so my quick-and-dirty idea was to define a table type in my package spec and a `PIPELINED` function in my package spec/body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_schema.api IS
  TYPE student_tab IS TABLE OF shared.student_utils.student_rec;

  FUNCTION get_all_student_data(student_id IN student.id%TYPE) RETURN student_tab PIPELINED;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_schema.api IS
  FUNCTION get_all_student_data(student_id IN student.id%TYPE) RETURN student_tab PIPELINED IS
  BEGIN
    PIPE ROW(shared.student_utils.get_student(student_id));
  END;
END;
```

...which lets me select it like so:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(my_schema.api.get_all_student_data(1234));
```

This works, but building a pipelined table just for one row is overkill, and Oracle's explain plan seems to agree.

Supposedly in Oracle 12c, there should be more options available:

> [More PL/SQL-Only Data Types Can Cross PL/SQL-to-SQL Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/release_changes.htm#GUID-57E439FB-B196-46CB-857C-0ADAB32D9EA0)

...but I can't seem to figure it out in my scenario. Changing the function to:

```
FUNCTION get_all_student_data RETURN student_tab IS
  r_student_tab student_tab;
BEGIN
  r_student_tab(1) := shared.student_utils.get_student(student_id);

  RETURN r_student_tab;
END;
```

...will compile, but I cannot `SELECT` from it as before.

OK, enough rambling, here's my actual question - what is the most direct method to call a PL/SQL function that returns a record type and select/manipulate the result in SQL?

Comment: maybe this link will help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020348/oracle-select-from-record-datatype

Comment: My **personal(!) feeling** is: You often see Oracle Object types in student books and tutorials and they are a big topic in many PL/SQL trainings. However, in reality Object types are hardly used in productive applications. "Hardly" does not mean "never" - but I just have the impression they are more handled in education than in production.

Comment: @eifla001 After more carefully reading the question you linked, it seems to answer my question rather fully. I have no idea why, in all my searching, I never found that question myself. Hopefully dupe-targeting it will help the next person find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The killer line [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/release_changes.htm#GUID-57E439FB-B196-46CB-857C-0ADAB32D9EA0) is this one:

> A PL/SQL function cannot return a value of a PL/SQL-only type to SQL.

That appears to rule out querying directly from a function which returns a PL/SQL Record or associative array like this:

```
select * from table(student_utils.get_students(7890));
```

What does work is this, which is technically SQL (because the docs define anonymous blocks as SQL not PL/SQL):

```
declare
    ltab student_utils.students_tab;
    lrec student_utils.student_rec;
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    ltab := student_utils.get_students(1234);
    open rc for select * from table(ltab);
    fetch rc into lrec;
    dbms_output.put_line(lrec.name);
    close rc;
end;
/
```

This is rather lame. I suppose there are a few times when we want to open a ref cursor from an array rather than just opening it for the SQL we would use to populate the array, but it's not the most pressing of use cases.

The problem is Oracle's internal architecture: the kernel has C modules for SQL and C modules for PL/SQL (this is why you will hear people talking about "context switches"). Exposing more PL/SQL capabilities to the SQL engine requires modifying the interfaces. We can only imagine how difficult it is to allow the SQL compiler to work against the definitions of PL/SQL data structures, which are extremely unstable (potentially they can change every time we run `create or replace package ...`.

Of course this does work for PIPELINED functions but that's because under the bonnet Oracle creates SQL types for the PL/SQL types referenced in the function. It cannot create objects on the fly for an arbitrary function we might wish to slip into a `table()` call. Some day it might be possible but just consider this one sticking point: what happens when a user who has execute on our package but lacks CREATE TYPE privilege tries to use the function?

Comment: +1, thanks, this makes sense. So what does it mean, then, that in 12c "More PL/SQL-Only Data Types Can Cross PL/SQL-to-SQL Interface"?

Comment: Steven Feuerstein has published a LiveSQL demo of the sort of new things these changes enable. [Find it here](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CHREI3LLPBLRAHQR9TDJIO677.html)