# oracle / return multiple values as multiple columns

Tags: oracle

I need to create a procedure or function (not sure yet) that return multiple values as separated columns

```
...
ID1 :=1;
ID2 :='test';
```

the result must be as shown below:

```
ID1  ID2
--------
1    test
```

I tried to create a type(ID1,ID2) and return it from a function , but the result was a type , what I need is simply multiple columns.

how to proceed here ?

Comment: Maybe table functions / pipelined table functions are what you are looking for. Search for those terms.

Comment: How do you intend to use the values once they are returned?  That information will help to decide how to design the solution.  Please edit the original post with this information.

Comment: What is the *input*? Where do those ID1 and ID2 come from? Once we know it, we'll have - as I said - the *input* and you described what is supposed to be the *output*. And we, we'll try to help you create a *black box* which will do the transformation.

Comment: maybe this link can help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020348/oracle-select-from-record-datatype