# Use rowtype from function in select - PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following function  -

```
  function f_get_emp_details(i_emp_no in t_emp.emp_no) return t_emp%rowtype is 
       l_emp_row t_emp%rowtype;
    Begin
      select *
      into l_emp_row
      from t_emp
      where t_emp.emp_no = i_emp_no;
    
    return l_emp_row;

    exception when others then
           return null;
    end;
```

And I have a cursor in other procedure -

```
    open c_tasks
      select task_id, 
             task_name,
             f_get_emp_details(t_task.emp_no)
      from t_task;
```

How can I used the function in select? I need multiple fields as used in the function.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve]. What is the benefit of using the function in your cursor, rather than just joining to the `t_emp` table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1020348/1509264 (since `%ROWTYPE` is implicitly a record type). However, if you make it a `PIPELINED` function returning a table of records then, depending on your Oracle version, it may work (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1556296/1509264) to the same question).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to get complex type in such way, you need to use object types, like this:

```
create or replace type t_emp_type is object(
  id     int,
  emp_no int,
  extra  varchar2(30)
);
```

Full example: and [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=af691e479236dc3f5b7e15e14fed5ba0): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=af691e479236dc3f5b7e15e14fed5ba0

```sql
create table t_emp(
  id     int,
  emp_no int,
  extra  varchar2(30)
);
create table t_task(
  task_id   int, 
  task_name varchar2(30),
  emp_no    int
);
insert into t_emp
  select level-1,level-1,'extra #'||(level-1)
  from dual
  connect by level<=10;
insert into t_task
  select level, 'task #'||level, mod(level,10) as emp_no
  from dual
  connect by level<=30;

create or replace type t_emp_type is object(
  id     int,
  emp_no int,
  extra  varchar2(30)
);

create or replace
  function f_get_emp_details(i_emp_no in t_emp.emp_no%type) return t_emp_type is 
       l_emp_row t_emp%rowtype;
    Begin
      select *
      into l_emp_row
      from t_emp
      where t_emp.emp_no = i_emp_no;
    
    return t_emp_type(l_emp_row.id, l_emp_row.emp_no, l_emp_row.extra);
    end;
/
select task_id, 
       task_name,
       (emp_details).id,
       (emp_details).emp_no,
       (emp_details).extra
from (
  select task_id, 
         task_name,
         f_get_emp_details(t_task.emp_no) emp_details
  from t_task
);
```

Results:

```
   TASK_ID TASK_NAME       (EMP_DETAILS).ID (EMP_DETAILS).EMP_NO (EMP_DETAILS).EXTRA
---------- --------------- ---------------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 task #1                        1                    1 extra #1
         2 task #2                        2                    2 extra #2
         3 task #3                        3                    3 extra #3
         4 task #4                        4                    4 extra #4
         5 task #5                        5                    5 extra #5
         6 task #6                        6                    6 extra #6
         7 task #7                        7                    7 extra #7
         8 task #8                        8                    8 extra #8
         9 task #9                        9                    9 extra #9
        10 task #10                       0                    0 extra #0
        11 task #11                       1                    1 extra #1
        12 task #12                       2                    2 extra #2
        13 task #13                       3                    3 extra #3
        14 task #14                       4                    4 extra #4
        15 task #15                       5                    5 extra #5
        16 task #16                       6                    6 extra #6
        17 task #17                       7                    7 extra #7
        18 task #18                       8                    8 extra #8
        19 task #19                       9                    9 extra #9
        20 task #20                       0                    0 extra #0
        21 task #21                       1                    1 extra #1
        22 task #22                       2                    2 extra #2
        23 task #23                       3                    3 extra #3
        24 task #24                       4                    4 extra #4
        25 task #25                       5                    5 extra #5
        26 task #26                       6                    6 extra #6
        27 task #27                       7                    7 extra #7
        28 task #28                       8                    8 extra #8
        29 task #29                       9                    9 extra #9
        30 task #30                       0                    0 extra #0

30 rows selected.
```